# How do I discover Service UUIDs and Characterstic UUIDs with react-native-ble-plx?

Tags: javascript, bluetooth-lowenergy, react-native, react-native-ble-plx

### Question:

I'm trying to connect to my bluetooth device, however upon connecting and discovering all services and characteristics, I'm unable to advance because the information returned is insufficient. I receive no service UUIDs nor any characteristic UUIDs.

What do I need to do to be able to access the UUIDs to then be able to read from the characteristics?

### What I've tried:

My device after calling `device.discoverAllServicesAndCharacteristics();` returns:

`{ _40: 0, _65: 0, _55: null, _72: null }`

and when I log `device` I get:

```
06-23 16:36:54.758  4397  4597 I ReactNativeJS: { isConnectable: null,
06-23 16:36:54.758  4397  4597 I ReactNativeJS:   rssi: null,
06-23 16:36:54.758  4397  4597 I ReactNativeJS:   serviceData: null,
06-23 16:36:54.758  4397  4597 I ReactNativeJS:   overflowServiceUUIDs: null,
06-23 16:36:54.758  4397  4597 I ReactNativeJS:   mtu: 23,
06-23 16:36:54.758  4397  4597 I ReactNativeJS:   localName: null,
06-23 16:36:54.758  4397  4597 I ReactNativeJS:   manufacturerData: null,
06-23 16:36:54.758  4397  4597 I ReactNativeJS:   txPowerLevel: null,
06-23 16:36:54.758  4397  4597 I ReactNativeJS:   id: '00:1E:C0:65:D7:DB',
06-23 16:36:54.758  4397  4597 I ReactNativeJS:   solicitedServiceUUIDs: null,
06-23 16:36:54.758  4397  4597 I ReactNativeJS:   name: 'RND7DB',
06-23 16:36:54.758  4397  4597 I ReactNativeJS:   serviceUUIDs: null,
06-23 16:36:54.758  4397  4597 I ReactNativeJS:   _manager:
06-23 16:36:54.758  4397  4597 I ReactNativeJS:    { _eventEmitter:
06-23 16:36:54.758  4397  4597 I ReactNativeJS:       { _subscriber:
06-23 16:36:54.758  4397  4597 I ReactNativeJS:          { _subscriptionsForType:
06-23 16:36:54.758  4397  4597 I ReactNativeJS:             { appStateDidChange:
06-23 16:36:54.758  4397  4597 I ReactNativeJS:                [ { subscriber: [Circular],
06-23 16:36:54.758  4397  4597 I ReactNativeJS:                    emitter:
06-23 16:36:54.758  4397  4597 I ReactNativeJS:                     { _subscriber: [Circular],
06-23 16:36:54.758  4397  4597 I ReactNativeJS:                       isAvailable: true,
06-23 16:36:54.758  4397  4597 I ReactNativeJS:                       _eventHandlers: { change: {}, memoryWarning: {} },
06-23 16:36:54.758  4397  4597 I ReactNativeJS:                       currentState: 'active' },
06-23 16:36:54.758  4397  4597 I ReactNativeJS:                    listener: [Function],
06-23 16:36:54.758  4397  4597 I ReactNativeJS:                    context: undefined,
06-23 16:36:54.758  4397  4597 I ReactNativeJS:                    eventType: 'appStateDidChange',
06-23 16:36:54.758  4397  4597 I ReactNativeJS:                    key: 0 } ],
06-23 16:36:54.758  4397  4597 I ReactNativeJS:               websocketMessage: [ , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , ,  ],
06-23 16:36:54.758  4397  4597 I ReactNativeJS:               websocketOpen: [ , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , ,  ],
06-23 16:36:54.758  4397  4597 I ReactNativeJS:               websocketClosed: [ , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , ,  ],
06-23 16:36:54.758  4397  4597 I ReactNativeJS:               websocketFailed: [ , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , ,  ],
06-23 16:36:54.758  4397  4597 I ReactNativeJS:               didUpdateDimensions:
06-23 16:36:54.758  4397  4597 I ReactNativeJS:                [ { subscriber: [Circular],
06-23 16:36:54.758  4397  4597 I ReactNativeJS:                    emitter:
06-23 16:36:54.758  4397  4597 I ReactNativeJS:                     { _subscriber: [Circular],
06-23 16:36:54.758  4397  4597 I ReactNativeJS:                       sharedSubscriber: [Circular],
06-23 16:36:54.758  4397  4597 I ReactNativeJS:                       _currentSubscription: null },
06-23 16:36:54.758  4397  4597 I ReactNativeJS:                    listener: [Function],
06-23 16:36:54.758  4397  4597 I ReactNativeJS:                    context: undefined,
06-23 16:36:54.758  4397  4597 I ReactNativeJS:                    eventType: 'didUpdateDimensions',
06-23 16:36:54.758  4397  4597 I ReactNativeJS:                    key: 0 } ],
06-23 16:36:54.758  4397  4597 I ReactNativeJS:               hardwareBackPress:
06-23 16:36:54.758  4397  4597 I ReactNativeJS:                [ { subscriber: [Circular],
06-23 16:36:54.758  4397  4597 I ReactNativeJS:                    emitter:
06-23 16:36:54.758  4397  4597 I ReactNativeJS:                     { _subscriber: [Circular],
06-23 16:36:54.758  4397  4597 I ReactNativeJS:                       sharedSubscriber: [Circular],
06-23 16:36:54.758  4397  4597 I ReactNativeJS:                       _currentSubscription: null },
06-23 16:36:54.758  4397  4597 I ReactNativeJS:                    listener: [Function],
06-23 16:36:54.758  4397  4597 I ReactNativeJS:                    context: undefined,
06-23 16:36:54.758  4397  4597 I ReactNativeJS:                    eventType: 'hardwareBackPress',
06-23 16:36:54.758  4397  4597 I ReactNativeJS:                    key: 0 } ],
06-23 16:36:54.758  4397  4597 I ReactNativeJS:               collectBugExtraData:
06-23 16:36:54.758  4397  4597 I ReactNativeJS:                [ { subscriber: [Circular],
06-23 16:36:54.758  4397  4597 I ReactNativeJS:                    emitter:
06-23 16:36:54.758  4397  4597 I ReactNativeJS:                     { _subscriber: [Circular],
06-23 16:36:54.758  4397  4597 I ReactNativeJS:                       sharedSubscriber: [Circular],
06-23 16:36:54.758  4397  4597 I ReactNativeJS:                       _currentSubscription: null },
06-23 16:36:54.758  4397  4597 I ReactNativeJS:                    listener: [Function: collectExtraData],
06-23 16:36:54.758  4397  4597 I ReactNativeJS:                    context: null,
06-23 16:36:54.758  4397  4597 I ReactNativeJS:                    eventType: 'collectBugExtraData',
06-23 16:36:54.758  4397  4597 I ReactNativeJS:                    key: 0 } ],
06-23 16:36:54.758  4397  4597 I ReactNativeJS:               collectRedBoxExtraData:
06-23 16:36:54.758  4397  4597 I ReactNativeJS:                [ { subscriber: [Circular],
06-23 16:36:54.758  4397  4597 I ReactNativeJS:                    emitter:
06-23 16:36:54.758  4397  4597 I ReactNativeJS:                     { _subscriber: [Circular],
06-23 16:36:54.758  4397  4597 I ReactNativeJS:                       sharedSubscriber: [Circular],
06-23 16:36:54.758  4397  4597 I ReactNativeJS:                       _currentSubscription: null },
06-23 16:36:54.758  4397  4597 I ReactNativeJS:                    listener: [Function: collectExtraData],
06-23 16:36:54.758  4397  4597 I ReactNativeJS:                    context: null,
06-23 16:36:54.758  4397  4597 I ReactNativeJS:                    eventType: 'collectRedBoxExtraData',
06-23 16:36:54.758  4397  4597 I ReactNativeJS:                    key: 0 } ],
06-23 16:36:54.758  4397  4597 I ReactNativeJS:               url:
06-23 16:36:54.758  4397  4597 I ReactNativeJS:                [ { subscriber: [Circular],
06-23 16:36:54.758  4397  4597 I ReactNativeJS:                    emitter: { _subscriber: [Circular] },
06-23 16:36:54.758  4397  4597 I ReactNativeJS:                    listener: [Function],
06-23 16:36:54.758  4397  4597 I ReactNativeJS:                    context: undefined,
06-23 16:36:54.758  4397  4597 I ReactNativeJS:                    eventType: 'url',
06-23 16:36:54.758  4397  4597 I ReactNativeJS:                    key: 0 },
06-23 16:36:54.758  4397  4597 I ReactNativeJS:                  { subscriber: [Circular],
06-23 16:36:54.758  4397  4597 I ReactNativeJS:                    emitter: { _subscriber: [Circular] },
06-23 16:36:54.758  4397  4597 I ReactNativeJS:                    listener: [Function],
06-23 16:36:54.758  4397  4597 I ReactNativeJS:                    context: undefined,
06-23 16:36:54.758  4397  4597 I ReactNativeJS:                    eventType: 'url',
06-23 16:36:54.758  4397  4597 I ReactNativeJS:                    key: 1 } ],
06-23 16:36:54.758  4397  4597 I ReactNativeJS:               toggleElementInspector:
06-23 16:36:54.758  4397  4597 I ReactNativeJS:                [ { subscriber: [Circular],
06-23 16:36:54.758  4397  4597 I ReactNativeJS:                    emitter:
06-23 16:36:54.758  4397  4597 I ReactNativeJS:                     { _subscriber: [Circular],
06-23 16:36:54.758  4397  4597 I ReactNativeJS:                       sharedSubscriber: [Circular],
06-23 16:36:54.758  4397  4597 I ReactNativeJS:                       _currentSubscription: null },
06-23 16:36:54.758  4397  4597 I ReactNativeJS:                    listener: [Function],
06-23 16:36:54.758  4397  4597 I ReactNativeJS:                    context: undefined,
06-23 16:36:54.758  4397  4597 I ReactNativeJS:                    eventType: 'toggleElementInspector',
06-23 16:36:54.758  4397  4597 I ReactNativeJS:                    key: 0 },
06-23 16:36:54.758  4397  4597 I ReactNativeJS:                  { subscriber: [Circular],
06-23 16:36:54.758  4397  4597 I ReactNativeJS:                    emitter:
06-23 16:36:54.758  4397  4597 I ReactNativeJS:                     { _subscriber: [Circular],
06-23 16:36:54.758  4397  4597 I ReactNativeJS:                       sharedSubscribe
```

At this point, I do not know what to do as I have received no valuable information to further get information from a characteristic.

According to the [docs](https://github.com/Polidea/react-native-ble-plx/wiki/Characteristic-Reading), I need the UUIDs to read from my device.

```
device.readCharacteristicForService(
  serviceUUID: UUID,
  characteristicUUID: UUID,
  transactionId: ?TransactionId
): Promise<Characteristic>
```

*Note: When I use Ble Scanner app on android, I'm able to receive all services and characteristics with their UUIDs.*

### Code snippet:

```
    @action connect = (deviceName) => {

        const device = this.devices.find(device=>device.name === deviceName);

        if(device === undefined){
            this.info = "Couldn't find device";
            return;
        }

        this.manager.stopDeviceScan();
        this.selectedDevice = device;
        this.selectedDevice
            .connect()
            .then((device) => {
                this.info = "Discovering services and characteristics";
                return device.discoverAllServicesAndCharacteristics();
            })
            .then((device) => {
                this.info = "Setting notifications";
                return this.setupNotifications(device)
            })
            .then(() => {
                this.info = "Listening..."
            }, (error) => {
                this.info = error.message;
            })
    };

 async setupNotifications(device) {
    console.log(device);
    console.log(this.manager.servicesForDevice(device.id));
}
```

[github issue #293](https://github.com/Polidea/react-native-ble-plx/issues/293)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here’s how I use it, hope it could help

```
 const { updateCharacteristic } = this.props
 const connectedDevice = await manager.connectToDevice(device.id)
 const services = await connectedDevice.discoverAllServicesAndCharacteristics()
 const characteristic = await this.getServicesAndCharacteristics(services)

getServicesAndCharacteristics(device) {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                device.services().then(services => {
                    const characteristics = []

                    services.forEach((service, i) => {
                        service.characteristics().then(c => {
                            characteristics.push(c)

                            if (i === services.length - 1) {
                                const temp = characteristics.reduce(
                                    (acc, current) => {
                                        return [...acc, ...current]
                                    },
                                    []
                                )
                                const dialog = temp.find(
                                    characteristic =>
                                        characteristic.isWritableWithoutResponse
                                )
                                if (!dialog) {
                                    reject('No writable characteristic')
                                }
                                resolve(dialog)
                            }
                        })
                    })
                })
            })
        }
```

Best regards.